# CSS Injector not serving most current version

Tags: theming, caching

I have made changes to a CSS Injector rule on my Drupal 7 site. Despite flushing all the caches several times, the CSS file that is included on the live site is not the most current version of the CSS Injector rule. When I look in the `<head>` section of the page, I find the CSS Injector file listed like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/.../css_injector_1.css?nzorcx" media="all">
```

The part that is confusing to me is the parameter tacked on to the end of the file name: ***?nzorcx***

If I access the CSS file without the `?nzorcx`, the CSS file *is* the most current version. So it would appear that `?nzorcx` is some kind of version thing. Fine. But how do I force it to refresh with the most current version. As mentioned, I've flushed all of the caches already.

Comment: perhaps the new css is wrong? have you tried deleting everything to see if indeed nothing is changing? (back up your css 1st, ofcourse)

Comment: The parameter is the versioning. It is a way to force the browser to reload a same named file that has previously been cached in the browser. Can also be done also with images etc.